# How to set Interval on a vuex state and clear that from template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to keep track of a page visit time in Nuxt by starting a setInterval function at mounted and clearInterval at destroyed. But I need to set the function in a vuex state. My approach is as following:

```
//_index.vue
mounted() 
{
   this.$store.dispatch('business/initiate_timer');
},    

destroyed() {
   this.$store.dispatch('business/clear_timer');
      
   var timerPayload = {}
   timerPayload.time = this.$store.state.business.timer / 60;
   this.$store.dispatch('business/action_to_post_request_with_timer', timerPayload)
 }
```

here is my timer related tasks on my moduled store: business.js

```
//business.js

export const state = () => ({
  timer: 0,
  refTimer: null,

})

export const mutations = {
start_timer(state){
    state.refTimer = setInterval(()=>{state.timer = state.timer + 1}, 1000)
  },
  clear_timer(state){
    clearInterval(state.refTimer)
  },
}


export const actions = {
  

  initiate_timer({commit})
  {
    commit('start_timer')
  },

  clear_timer({commit})
  {
    commit('clear_timer')
  },
}
```

I am getting error

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

And it keeps coming on every one secound interval. So the function is being called, but giving me this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to steer clear of set intervals, You can do this by getting the current date time at load.

```
//_index.vue
mounted() 
{
   this.loaded = new Date();
},
methods() {
    timeOnPage() {
        const diff = (this.loaded.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
        return Math.abs(Math.round(diff/60));
    }
},

destroyed() {
    this.$store.dispatch('business/action_to_post_request_with_timer', this.timeOnPage());
 }
```